# Woocommerce API HTTP Response 401

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I believe you're my last hope with what I'm trying to do. I want to integrate UK Royalmail Woocommerce Plugin with my Woocommerce web app. When I'm adding a new integration with my store url, I'm getting a response `WooCommerce API returned HTTP response [401]`. It looks like that might not be the only one plugin that is not going through my firewall, I tried to get a domain key from LiteSpeed Cache plugin, I don't have any response error but it takes forever to get this key, so I bet it's something on my website's firewall. What I tried is whitelisting IPs, modifying .htaccess file, doing some apache2 changes, switching ufw settings, but non of these really worked. Also browsed many of answers here on stack, but these also failed. Maybe here would be someone who knows what I could do more in order to enable integration with my plugins? Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you sure it's the firewall - do you see the 401s in your apache logs? Do the 401 error messages say 'Apache' in the headers or response body?

Comment: If it is being rejected by WordPress, how are you authenticating yourself to your API? It could be one of your plugins has changed the mechanism or added extra restrictions.

Comment: The 401 I get is on the RoyalMail website while I'm trying to integrate their services with my website. I was curious if one of my plugins does block these. I have Ajax Search, Contact Form 7, Elementor, Enhanced Meda Lib, Google Analytics, Limit log in attempts, LiteSpeed Cache, Ocean Extra, White Label, WooCommerce + Paypal + Stripe + pdf invoices, WP fail2ban and WP Hardening. I was trying to disable them in order to check this but unsuccessfully

Comment: @Rup you were right! That was one of my plugins. I have browsed my access.log for apache2 and there was a GET request from RoyalMail to /wp-json/wc/v2 which I literally blocked to be public using WP Hardening Plugin. Thank you mate for your help